# How to create a new timestamp(minute) column in a CSV file using scala/python/spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a CSV file and I want to create a new minute timestamp column as shown below

Actual:

```
Col1, Col2
1.19185711131486, 0.26615071205963  
-1.3598071336738, -0.0727811733098497   
-0.966271711572087, -0.185226008082898
-0.966271711572087, -0.185226008082898
-1.15823309349523, 0.877736754848451
-0.425965884412454, 0.960523044882985
```

Expected:

```
Col1, Col2, ts
1.19185711131486, 0.26615071205963, 00:00:00
-1.3598071336738, -0.0727811733098497, 00:01:00
-0.966271711572087, -0.185226008082898, 00:02:00
-0.966271711572087, -0.185226008082898, 00:03:00
-1.15823309349523, 0.877736754848451, 00:04:00
-0.425965884412454, 0.960523044882985, 00:05:00
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How do you build the minutes column?

Comment: @Rolintocour that's why I posted a question.

Comment: @Rolintocour meant you can explain in word (in the ques body) what is the logic behind the expected output (ts column)

Answer (score 0):

perhaps this is useful -

```scala
 val data =
      """
        |Col1, Col2
        |1.19185711131486, 0.26615071205963
        |-1.3598071336738, -0.0727811733098497
        |-0.966271711572087, -0.185226008082898
        |-0.966271711572087, -0.185226008082898
        |-1.15823309349523, 0.877736754848451
        |-0.425965884412454, 0.960523044882985
      """.stripMargin
    val stringDS = data.split(System.lineSeparator())
      .map(_.split("\\,").map(_.replaceAll("""^[ \t]+|[ \t]+$""", "")).mkString(","))
      .toSeq.toDS()
    val df = spark.read
      .option("sep", ",")
      .option("inferSchema", "true")
      .option("header", "true")
      .option("nullValue", "null")
      .csv(stringDS)
    df.printSchema()
    df.show(false)
    /**
      * root
      * |-- Col1: double (nullable = true)
      * |-- Col2: double (nullable = true)
      *
      * +------------------+-------------------+
      * |Col1              |Col2               |
      * +------------------+-------------------+
      * |1.19185711131486  |0.26615071205963   |
      * |-1.3598071336738  |-0.0727811733098497|
      * |-0.966271711572087|-0.185226008082898 |
      * |-0.966271711572087|-0.185226008082898 |
      * |-1.15823309349523 |0.877736754848451  |
      * |-0.425965884412454|0.960523044882985  |
      * +------------------+-------------------+
      */
```

```scala
    df.withColumn("ts",
      date_format(to_timestamp((row_number().over(Window.orderBy(df.columns.map(col): _*)) - 1).cast("string"),
        "mm")
        , "00:mm:00"))
      .show(false)

    /**
      * +------------------+-------------------+--------+
      * |Col1              |Col2               |ts      |
      * +------------------+-------------------+--------+
      * |-1.3598071336738  |-0.0727811733098497|00:00:00|
      * |-1.15823309349523 |0.877736754848451  |00:01:00|
      * |-0.966271711572087|-0.185226008082898 |00:02:00|
      * |-0.966271711572087|-0.185226008082898 |00:03:00|
      * |-0.425965884412454|0.960523044882985  |00:04:00|
      * |1.19185711131486  |0.26615071205963   |00:05:00|
      * +------------------+-------------------+--------+
      */
```

Comment: It works fine up to  "00:59:00" after that it shows "null".
Actually it's a sample data and I want to generate it for thousands of records.

Comment: Will check it once i get sometime..but why it is downvoted

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure. Someone else downvoted. But your information is really useful to me.

Comment: agreed. Hi @Sudhakar, why can't you provide the logic to get `ts` column? this will help you in turn to get quality answers

Comment: @Sudhakar, what do you expect for rows after `00:59:00` value?

Comment: If you have no performance constraint, you could use an UDF with regular scala / Java code?

Comment: @SomeshwarKale after ```00:59:00``` it has to be ```01:00:00, 01:01:00```, and so on. But I managed to get this done. Thanks for your help.